# Class not being added in method when using $(this) selector

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-selectors

Can someone explain why this code works:

```
$('#FonykerUsernameRegister').blur(function(){
            if($(this).val().length > 2) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo $html->url('/fonykers/validate_username',true); ?>' + '/' + $(this).val(),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(response) {
                        if(!response.ok) {
                            $('#FonykerUsernameRegister').addClass('error');
                            error.html(response.msg);
                            error.fadeIn();
                        } else {
                            if($('#FonykerUsernameRegister').is('.error')) {
                                $('#FonykerUsernameRegister').removeClass('error');
                            }
                            $('#FonykerUsernameRegister').addClass('ok');
                        }
                    },
                    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        alert(xhr.statusText);
                        alert(thrownError);
                    } 
                });        
            } else {
               error.html('Username must have at least 3 characters');
               error.fadeIn();
               $('#FonykerUsernameRegister').addClass('error');
            }
        });
```

As opposed to this one:

```
$('#FonykerUsernameRegister').blur(function(){
            if($(this).val().length > 2) {
                $.ajax({
                    url: '<?php echo $html->url('/fonykers/validate_username',true); ?>' + '/' + $(this).val(),
                    dataType: 'json',
                    type: 'POST',
                    success: function(response) {
                        if(!response.ok) {
                            $(this).addClass('error');
                            error.html(response.msg);
                            error.fadeIn();
                        } else {
                            if($(this).is('.error')) {
                                $(this).removeClass('error');
                            }
                            $(this).addClass('ok');
                        }
                    },
                    error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                        alert(xhr.statusText);
                        alert(thrownError);
                    } 
                });        
            } else {
               error.html('Username must have at least 3 characters');
               error.fadeIn();
               $(this).addClass('error');
            }
        });
```

I'm assuming the second one is a bit more optimized so I'd rather use that way if possible, but it just isn't setting the classes on the elements.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first code (working code) refers to the element by id: the jQuery `$` function is basically a replacement for `document.getElementById`.

In the second code, when you try to reference the element using `this`, the scope is such that `this` will likely refer to the request object or `window`. The solution, if you want to use the `this` object with the scope you desire, is to use the `proxy` method to bind the handler function, or grab the target element as a variable to use in a closure.

Of the two methods, using `proxy` is the the least likely to end up causing a circular reference. The code you've given here is safe, but you really have to watch yourself when you use element references in closures if the target element will be removed from DOM at some point - you'd then potentially have a situation where the browser's garbage collector cannot free the resources related to the element because the closure is holding open a reference pointer.

All `proxy` does is to create a closure with the specified scope, see the docs [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/).

For further reading on scope, check out [this MDC document](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) and this [MDC scope "cheat sheet"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet)

**Closure:**

```
$('#FonykerUsernameRegister').blur(function(){
    var target = $(this);
    if($(this).val().length > 2) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $html->url('/fonykers/validate_username',true); ?>' + '/' + $(this).val(),
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: function(response) {
                if(!response.ok) {
                    target.addClass('error');
                    error.html(response.msg);
                    error.fadeIn();
                } else {
                    if(target.is('.error')) {
                        target.removeClass('error');
                    }
                    target.addClass('ok');
                }
            },
            error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(xhr.statusText);
                alert(thrownError);
                alert(target);
            } 
        });        
    } else {
       error.html('Username must have at least 3 characters');
       error.fadeIn();
       $(this).addClass('error');
    }
});
```

**Proxy**

```
$('#FonykerUsernameRegister').blur(function(){
    if($(this).val().length > 2) {
        $.ajax({
            url: '<?php echo $html->url('/fonykers/validate_username',true); ?>' + '/' + $(this).val(),
            dataType: 'json',
            type: 'POST',
            success: $.proxy(function(response) {
                if(!response.ok) {
                    $(this).addClass('error');
                    error.html(response.msg);
                    error.fadeIn();
                } else {
                    if($(this).is('.error')) {
                        this.removeClass('error');
                    }
                    $(this).addClass('ok');
                }
            }, this),
            error:$.proxy(function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                alert(xhr.statusText);
                alert(thrownError);
                alert(this);
            }, this) 
        });        
    } else {
       error.html('Username must have at least 3 characters');
       error.fadeIn();
       $(this).addClass('error');
    }
});
```

Comment: You forgot to wrap it with jQuery: `var target = this;` -> `var target = $(this);`

Comment: That is unnecessary when the code below wraps it in `$` on a per-use basis. Essentially equivalent, though the method used here (taken from the OP, not my code) is slightly less efficient.

Comment: My point is that you don't wrap it in the original code you posted (not the proxy code). See: `target.is('.error')`, `target.removeClass('error');`, `target.addClass('ok');` Those are functions on a jQuery object not on a DOM element.

Comment: Ha, right on.  You can always edit an answer to correct something small like that. Corrected.

Comment: Yeah, I don't usually edit answers. Especially close to the posting time since the user may be editing it again.

Answer (score 2):

Because "this" in the success handler do not points to the element(#FonykerUsernameRegister).

You can make use of closure in this case.

```
var $this = $(this); //Set this before you make a ajax call
```

and use $this in the success Handler;

```
success: function(response) {
                        if(!response.ok) {
                            $this.addClass('error');
                            error.html(response.msg);
                            error.fadeIn();
                        } else {
                            if($this.is('.error')) {
                                $this.removeClass('error');
                            }
                            $this.addClass('ok');
                        }
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

In the second version, the `this` pointer inside of the success callback no longer points to the jQuery selection - it points to the request object.  Try something like this:

```
$('#FonykerUsernameRegister').blur(function(){
    var self = this; // preserve the 'this' pointer
    $.ajax({
         // blabla
         success: function(response) {
             // replace all references to 'this' with 'self', eg
             $(self).addClass('error');

         }
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to stash the value of `this` for use inside those other (callback) functions.

At the top of the blur handler, add:

```
  var register = this, $register = $(register);
```

(Use other names of course, as you prefer.)

Then, inside the ajax handler functions, you can use "$register" instead of "$('#FonykerUsernameRegister')".

Answer (score 0):

The success callback is not called within the same context as the `.blur` callback, so `this` in the success callback is most likely is referring to the `window` or perhaps the ajax object. There's another way of doing this by caching the `$(this)` which will be passed into the success callback through the scope chain. See below:

```
$('#FonykerUsernameRegister').blur(function(){
        var $this = $(this); //Cache our reference to #FonykerUsernameRegister
        if($this.val().length > 2) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '<?php echo $html->url('/fonykers/validate_username',true); ?>' + '/' + $this.val(),
                dataType: 'json',
                type: 'POST',
                success: function(response) {
                    if(!response.ok) {
                        $this.addClass('error');
                        error.html(response.msg);
                        error.fadeIn();
                    } else {
                        if($this.is('.error')) {
                            $this.removeClass('error');
                        }
                        $this.addClass('ok');
                    }
                },
                error:function (xhr, ajaxOptions, thrownError){
                    alert(xhr.statusText);
                    alert(thrownError);
                } 
            });        
        } else {
           error.html('Username must have at least 3 characters');
           error.fadeIn();
           $this.addClass('error');
        }
    });
```